# Buttons' background being flickering or disappearing on Mouse Over

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I added a custom style on Mouse Over effect for the button in Resource Dictionary inside the App.xaml file. While on my computer, it is working perfectly but on some PC the button's background is flickering or disappearing on mouseover.

[image]

**App.xaml Code**

```
      <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="btn-danger" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">

                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#d84315" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />

                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Cursor="Hand">
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </Border>

                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>

                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#d9534f" />
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
```

**How is it being used**

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource btn-danger}" Margin="5" Click="Ok_Button_Click" Height="29" Width="100" Content="{Binding Path=Ok, Source={StaticResource Resources}}"/>
```

Comment: You've shared `btn-danger` style, which has `#d84315` background, I didn't observe any issues with it. I guess, that problem with `btn-primary` style, please share it

Comment: Sorry, I inserted the wrong code there.you are right, there should be btn-danger. The main problem is that it is working perfectly on my PC but while on some PC, this issue is occuring.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. All works good.

Comment: Try renaming the style to something more unique and retest. It could have been a different component that reloaded a button style with the same name.

Comment: @Shivam Manandhar - Can you expose part of the .xaml defining all buttons used the `btn-danger` style?

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to put the trigger under the template property, to border background be changed properly. Try to change the style definition as below:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
  <Style x:Key="btn-danger" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />                
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Cursor="Hand">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#d9534f" />                                    
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```